# No module named 'importlib.util' with Python 3.8

Tags: python, python-3.x

I encountered the following error:

```
  File "D:\python-win\lib\distutils\util.py", line 9, in <module>
    import importlib.util
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'importlib.util'
```

I am using python 3.8 (x64) on a windows 10 machine

```
D:\test> python --version 
Python 3.8.10
```

and the latest pip

```
(.venv) D:\test> pip --version 
pip 21.3.1 from d:\test\.venv\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.8)
```

As the above message indicates the error is originating from util.py which is included in the lib/dist folder of the python 3.8 distribution for windows. The offending block is

```
"""distutils.util

Miscellaneous utility functions -- anything that doesn't fit into
one of the other *util.py modules.
"""

import os
import re
import importlib.util
import string
import sys
from distutils.errors import DistutilsPlatformError
from distutils.dep_util import newer
from distutils.spawn import spawn
from distutils import log
from distutils.errors import DistutilsByteCompileError
```

All of the info I could find indicated importlib was included with python 3+, but I am seeing this error anyway.
Is there something else I am missing?

Comment: Can you show the code? Please

Comment: Could you provide few line of code in which that error appear? It is needed to better understand your issue.

Comment: Added the code from the offending util.py file. This is included in the distro so I did not think adding it was useful, but since it has been requested I have added it to the post.

Comment: Does `importlib/util.py` exist? Maybe it got deleted somehow.

Comment: `pip` doesn't seem relevant since [`importlib.util` is a standard library module](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/importlib.html#module-importlib.util).

Comment: To confirm, [`importlib` was added in 3.1](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html), including [`util`](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/importlib.html#module-importlib.util)

Comment: `importlib/util.py` does exist in the location referenced. It is from their I pulled the above code.